# If L is the laplacian matrix of an undirected graph, and D is a diagonal matrix, what does the cofactor of L+D look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants, algebraic-graph-theory

We know (e.g. [Godsil, Royle: Algebraic Graph Theory, [Lemma 13.2.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=GeSPBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA283)]) that any cofactor of the Laplacian matrix of a graph is constant, and is equal to the number of spanning trees of the graph. How do the cofactors change if I just add a diagonal matrix to the Laplacian matrix?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To point out an obvious thing: because of (Laplacian) + (diagonalmatrix with the negated vertex degrees on the diagonal) = (-adjacencymatrix), and since the cofactors of (-adjacencymatrix) equal the cofactors of the adjacencymatrix itself, this question *is at least as difficult as asking: What can appreciably be said in general about cofactors of adjacency matrices of undirected graphs?* This *seems* difficult and not to have been done.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at:

*Bapat, R.B.; Lal, A.K.; Pati, S.*, [**A formula for all minors of the adjacency matrix and an application**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2478/spma-2014-0009), Spec. Matrices 2, No. 1, 89-98 (2014). [ZBL1291.05117](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1291.05117).

which at least addresses the Peter Heinig comment.